# Extracting a single value from a data frame, given that time is the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the sample of a huge dataset I have:

```
   8/9/17   Dark_Si      0.0001036   360nm   0.0003071   380nm
   10:06:55 -0.0000659  -0.0000029  -2.80%  -0.0000037  -1.20%
   10:07:24 -0.0000669  -0.0000016  -1.54%  -0.0000017  -0.55%
   10:07:53 -0.0000662  -0.0000036  -3.47%  -0.0000033  -1.07%
   10:08:21 -0.0000653  -0.0000033  -3.19%  -0.0000038  -1.24%
   10:08:50 -0.0000647  -0.0000026  -2.51%  -0.0000029  -0.94%
   10:09:18 -0.000066   -0.0000035  -3.38%  -0.0000031  -1.01%
   10:09:47 -0.000065   -0.0000039  -3.76%  -0.0000035  -1.14%
```

I want to be able to extract a single value from a col of my choice that corresponds to a particular time in the index. I have tried the following:

```
   dfFR = pd.read_csv(path + file2, index_col = '8/9/17',skipinitialspace=True)
   print(dfFR.loc[[12:00:22]['360nm']])
```

And,

```
   print(dfFR.loc[dfFR['8/9/17'] == 12:00:22]['360nm'].values)
```

but neither works :( Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Try dfFR.loc['10:09:18', '360nm']

Comment: Try this: `df.loc[['10:08:50'], '360nm']`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That worked!!!! @Vaishali

Comment: Thank you @MaxU too!! both of them worked:D

Comment: Is there any way you can explain why my method didn't work? Thank you!